The audio strip I put in the video sequencer offsets every time I pause the timeline
I'm trying to make a music video, so I attached audio to the project to help me with timing. However, every time I pause to adjust something or write down a timestamp even if for just a second, the audio offsets itself unless I return to frame 0. This is extremely inconvenient and it really slows my workflow when I have to rewatch the whole animation just to check if something closer to the end of the song is timed right. (I'm not even sure if it's timed right anyway, because the preview speed might also differ from the selected framerate.) How can I make sure the right timestamps on the strip align correctly with the right range of frames? (I'm not concerned about the strip lining up with the render. I can add audio to the render in post. I just need it to line up in the viewport so I can make the darned thing.)

This can happen if your computer cannot handle the framerate. So just change:
in "playback" -> sync -> framedropping

This should solve your problem.
